# Override default function for handling ES6 template strings (quasi-literals)

Tags: ecmascript-6, template-strings

ES6 offers template strings, such as

```
`Hello ${name}`
```

In this case a default template builder is called. You can also use your own "tags":

```
tag`Hello ${name}`
```

where `tag` is a function which is passed information about the template string and generates a result.

My question is, is there any way to **override the default function** called when no tag is specified?

**Another question**: Is there any way to determine if the tag function is being called by the system to construct a template string, versus say being called directly, other than examining the first argument for a `raw` property?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:quasis says the default is a frozen function (without giving reasons), and the es6 draft spec doesn't seem to have a place where you could hook in. Might be worth asking on the es-discuss mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They are different syntactic productions with different semantic meanings. `` `stuff` `` is more akin to a string literal, whereas `` tag`stuff` `` is more akin to a function call.